# w2k12 password expired but no prompt to change it

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

our company server which we use as a terminal server and login via RDP behaves weird - when your password expires it tells you that password is expired and needs to be changed. But then there is no window dialog to change it! And it ends with a message that password is wrong. How can users change their password when it's expired?

Comment: There are some solutions here: https://superuser.com/questions/1196477/allow-users-to-change-expired-password-via-remote-desktop-connection. This inability to change the expired password is caused by requiring NLA on the RDP connection

Answer (score 1):

If the password as expired in the session, you need the user to relog with the new credential to have a valid token.

If they change the password by using CTRL-ALT-DEL->Change password's option, then they need to relog after too.

The best tip I used to do for my RDS's farm is to force the user password change at the **login** to the TS.

How I do it;

- I run a planned task each day at midnight to force the user expiration in Active Directory when a user is near the expiration day.

Like;

```
# This PowerShell Script will query Active Directory and return the user accounts with passwords 
# set to expire before the end of the next day, export a list of the affected accounts, and require
# a password change at the next logon.  The script is configured to ingore accounts which have been
# configured with passwords that never expire, and to ignore accounts who do not have permission to
# change their own password.  Any other account would be affected, so be warned before running this
# script, as you could experience unintended consequences.  Either modify the script to reduce the
# scope of user accounts, or ensure that accounts that shouldn't be affected are either flaged with
# a non-expiring password or are flagged with "cannot change password.  When ready to run/schedule 
# in production, remove the -WhatIf from the last line.
#
# - MWT, 10/11/13

# The 89 is based upon your environment. If passwords expire every X (90) days, and you run the script
# in the early morning, you can set it to -1*(X-1) (-89), if you run the script late at night, set it to
# -1*(X-2) (-88).

Import-Module ActiveDirectory # Required for PowerShell 2.0 only

$a = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-88)

# The following line will build the variable based upon the noted criteria
$b = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Contonso,DC=com" -Property Name,SamAccountName,PasswordLastSet,CannotChangePassword,PasswordNeverExpires -Filter {(PasswordLastSet -lt $a) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) -and (Enabled -eq $true)} | Where-Object {$_.CannotChangePassword -eq $false}

# The following line will display/export the data logging the accounts to be changed; please note the
# Out-File path and change to suit your needs.
$b | Format-Table Name,PasswordLastSet,CannotChangePassword,PasswordNeverExpires -AutoSize

# The following line will actually flag the accounts to require a password change (after -WhatIf is removed)
  $b | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true}
```

If your user only log into the Terminal Server you can change the password expiration warning from 14 days to 1 day. The script as I pasted it expire the account at -2 days (from a 90 days expiration), thus the user will never see the expiration warning, thus will never have a reminder to change their password inside their TS's session.

nb, If unsure you can test the script with -WhatIf on the last line, it will display user account it would reset the account without expiring them.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help, but honestly all I see are just workarounds and not an explanation why is this happening and our W2K12 R2 server does not let you change the password normally when it expires! I am pretty sure it was working. I have a home server also w2k12 R2 and just recently when I logged via RDP (I do it only this way) it told me - your password has expired, you must change it - here is the change dialog. And I just do it

Comment: can it be a result of some recent MS hotfix?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution is change the password in Active Directory Domain Service for a user.

In addition to above, apply the policy cited in the below link.

www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/74548-password-expiration-warning-change-time.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't as far as I'm aware. If the password has already expired they can't change it through the RDS server.

A few other options are :

1. Change it through OWA
2. Have the helpdesk change it
3. Configure a self service password system

It's been an issue with session based RDS since Terminal Services.

When we ran RDS I had implemented a password notification app that sent emails twice a day for the last 7 days of expiry and then 4 times a day for the last two. If a user had not changed their password by then and logged a helpdesk ticket it was mentioned in their meeting (name and shame ha ha).